(Group)Homomorphism and Subgroups
Given a group $G$, a normal subgroup $H$ and a (surjective) homomorphism $\pi: G \to G/H$. Via Isomorphism Theorem, it is known that $ |G| =  |Ker(\pi)||G/H|$. I understand this as grouping into cosets $gH =\{gh\mid h \in H \}$ that lay fully in $G$.
I'm trying to understand this behavior for subgroups. Given subgroup $X$, it is not generally true that $ |X| =  |\ker(\pi)||\pi(X)|$ (e.g. the trivial subgroup), however given a subgroup $A$ of $G/H $ then for subgroup $Y$ of $G$ with $Y=\pi^{-1}(A)$
$ |Y| =  |\ker(\pi)||A|$. I fail to find a intuition for this.
Furthermore, is it possible to restrict the homomorphism $\pi$ to $H$ (*K), and what happens to the kernel in relation to the original homomorphism?

There is a bijection between subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$ and subgroups of $G/H$. Subgroups $K$ of $G$ that contain $H$ do satisfy $|K|=|\ker(\pi)||\pi(K)|$. For arbitrary subgroups, note the image of $K$ equals the image of $KH$. In particular, $\pi$ cannot "distinguish" between the subgroup $K$ and the possibly larger subgroup $KH$. So the general equation valid for all subgroups is $|KH|=|\ker(\pi)||\pi(K)|$.

The Isomorphism Theorems establish that there is a bijection between the subgroups of $G/H$ and the subgroups of $G$ that contain $H$. the bijection is given by sending the subgroup $Y\leq G/H$ to $\pi^{-1}(Y)$, and sending the subgroup $K$ that contains $H$ to $\pi(K)$. For these subgroups of $G$, the equality $|K|=|\pi(K)||\ker(\pi)|$ does hold.
For an arbitrary subgroup $K$ of $G$, note that $\pi$ cannot distinguish between the subgroup $K$ and the subgroup $KH$ (which is a subgroup since $H$ is normal). Because $\pi(K)=\pi(KH)$. The formula does hold for $KH$. So in general, for arbitrary $K$, you have
$$|\pi(K)||\ker(\pi)| = |KH|.$$
As for $|KH|$, it satisfies the equation $|KH||K\cap H| = |K||H|$. This holds for any two subgroups $K$ and $H$, whether or not $KH$ is itself a subgroup.
Alternatively, you can consider the restriction of $\pi$ to $K$, which will give $|\pi(K)||\ker(\pi|_K)| = |K|$. And $\ker(\pi|_K) = K\cap H$. In fact, the isomorphism theorems tell us that
$$\frac{K}{K\cap H}\cong \frac{KH}{H},$$
which connects the equality above with the one mentioned before $|KH|=|\pi(K)||\ker(\pi)|$.
Finally, you ask what happens when you restrict $\pi$ to $H$. If you really meant $H$... then you get the trivial map sending $H$ to $H/H$, which is the trivial group. If you meant restricting to $K$, then what happens is described in the previous paragraph.

Thank you, exactly what I was missing. (For the last part: it was supposed to be K - edited)
